# Encountered NoClassDefFoundError when using Amazon AWS SDK

Tags: java, jsf-2, amazon-web-services, noclassdeffounderror

At the moment, in my test **`EJB project`**, I have the following `Stateless` bean:

```
@WebService(serviceName = "TestService")
@Stateless()
public class TestService {

    @WebMethod(operationName = "testUpload")
    public void testUpload() {
        // DUMMY LINE
        Log log = LogFactory.getLog(AmazonS3Client.class);
        // END DUMMY LINE

        File file = new File("path_to_test_file");
        AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(AMAZON_KEY_ID, AMAZON_SECRET_KEY);
        AmazonS3 conn = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
        conn.setEndpoint("https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com");
        PutObjectRequest por = new PutObjectRequest(AMAZON_BUCKET_NAME, "test.txt", file);
        conn.putObject(por);
    }

}
```

In my test **`WAR project`**, I have the following `ManagedBean`:

```
@Named(value = "mrBean")
@RequestScoped
public class MrBean {
    @WebServiceRef(wsdlLocation = "WEB-INF/wsdl/localhost_8080/TestService/TestService.wsdl")
    private TestService_Service service;
    private TestService port;

    @PostConstruct
    public void test() {
        port = service.getTestServicePort();
        port.testUpload();
    }
}
```

When I deploy my **`EJB project`** and run the `test.xhtml` page, I have always run into error at the following line:

```
AmazonS3 conn = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
```

In the beginning, the error looks like this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<clinit>(AmazonS3Client.java:193)
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
```

After a few trial runs, the error became:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client
```

There are a few weird things:

1. The weirdest thing is that if I copy the whole `testUpload()` function and paste into the `ManagedBean`, the function **works perfectly**. I'm 100% sure that I have imported all libraries on both projects. However, the function `testUpload()` can only work inside the **`WAR project`**, not the **`EJB project`**.
2. As you can see in the code above, I tried to add a dummy line `Log log = LogFactory.getLog(AmazonS3Client.class);` but the error was never thrown at that line.

I'd be extremely grateful if you could show me how to tackle this problem :(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the issue, I had to package the `EJB Project` inside an `EAR Project`. Only when I deploy the `EAR Project` instead of deploying the `EJB Project` directly then the libraries are loaded correctly.

I still haven't found out the cause of this problem. I'd be very grateful if someone could give me an explanation if possible :)